# PHP MySQL query 2 tables for data and combine into one json array for echo?

Tags: php, mysql, json

How to combine these 2 queries into one php array that echos back to ajax request in json format? Each statement is confirmed working alone.
Something that looks like:

```
 'fname' => $fname,
 'lname' => $lname,
'gender' => $gender,
  'city' => $city,
 'state' => $state
   'bio' => $bio
```

**PHP MySQL request**

```
<?php
include 'sqlconnection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT fname,lname,gender,city,state FROM users WHERE uid='.$_POST['info']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($fname,$lname,$gender,$city,$state);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $output=array(
        'fname' => $fname,
        'lname' => $lname,
        'gender' => $gender,
        'city' => $city,
        'state' => $state
    );
}
$json=json_encode($output);
echo $json;

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT bio FROM profile WHERE uid='.$_POST['info']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($bio);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $output=array(
        'bio' => $bio
    );
}
$json=json_encode($output);
echo $json;

$stmt->close();
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `JOIN` your two tables on `uid` to merge the two queries into one. Note you are not using prepared statements properly, you should put in a placeholder for `uid` and then use [`bind_param`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param) to attach a value:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT u.fname,u.lname,u.gender,u.city,u.state,p.bio
                        FROM users u
                        JOIN profile p ON p.uid = u.uid
                        WHERE u.uid=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['info']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($fname,$lname,$gender,$city,$state,$bio);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $output=array(
        'fname' => $fname,
        'lname' => $lname,
        'gender' => $gender,
        'city' => $city,
        'state' => $state,
        'bio' => $bio
    );
}
```

Note that if it's possible a user will not have an entry in the `profile` table, you should use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `JOIN`.

Comment: awesome, i really appreciate the help. what if i wanted to add a third table in there? all based on the same variable. like this? FROM users u LEFT JOIN profile p LEFT JOIN accout a ON p.uid,a.uid = u.uid?

Comment: @JamesBargon `FROM users u LEFT JOIN profile p ON p.uid=u.uid LEFT JOIN accout a ON a.uid = u.uid`

Comment: i see makes sense. thanks a lot! how do you have so much rep in just 2 years?

Comment: @JamesBargon too much time spent on the site? :-) but more to the point I've answered over 3300 questions...

Comment: yeah lol, thats what i mean. thats like like 1500+ a year, nearly 5 a day. do you have a full time job? if so, you must not have much spare time

Comment: @JamesBargon I'm sort of retired so plenty of free time.

Comment: i see, well thank you for your time. if i ever have a question (hopefully not for a while) could i ask you? i was trying to accept but i guess stack overflow makes me wait a certain period of time before i can accept.

Comment: @JamesBargon best to just ask and tag appropriately, I will almost certainly see it anyway but if not there are plenty of other smart people on this site.